# how to put stroke in java, android

Tags: android, android-studio

hey guys i want to put stroke in this code, but when i use the setStroke its not working. Can you help me to how to put stroke in this code.thank for any help, im newbie in android. I was trying to do this, put a white stroke on the gray box. How can I achieve this?  [image]

```
private static class Nub extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public Nub( Context context ) {

        super( context );

        paint.setStyle( Paint.Style.FILL );
        paint.setColor( 0xFF313231 );
        paint.setAntiAlias( true );

        path.lineTo( getDIP( context, 20 ), 0 );
        path.lineTo( getDIP( context, 10 ), getDIP( context, 15 ) );
        path.close();

    }
```

Comment: Since there is no setStroke method, it wouldn't.  There's multiple stroke functions for different variables in the stroke.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i want to do this "paint.setStroke(3, Color.WHITE)". its there another way to apply this codes

Comment: There is no such thing as setStroke on a paint.  I can guess what you're trying to do, but I can't be sure.  I think you're trying to use some other OS/framwork's definition of a paint to write that code.

Comment: i updated my question can you check it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `setStroke()` on `Paint`. Where are you trying to call `setStroke()`?

What I believe you want is

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); // should probably use a color resource here instead of hard coding
paint.setStrokeWidth(3); // you should probably do some px to dp conversion here
```

You will also have to add a call to

```
canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
```

once you have plotted out your path.